# How to set the Date Picker just below the button

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

I want to open a date picker by clicking on button.  But when I click on button, it will show a calendar in top left corner of the screen.  I want to see it just below the button.  How can I do it?

Also How can I change the size of calendar to make it little bit small?

Below is the example.

---

```
package practiceproblems; 

import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;

class DatePicker {  

int month = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
int year = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
JLabel l = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);  
String day = "";
JDialog d;
JButton[] button = new JButton[49];

public DatePicker(JFrame parent) {  
d = new JDialog();
d.setModal(true);
String[] header = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };
JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 7));
p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(430, 120));
for (int x = 0; x < button.length; x++) {
    final int selection = x;
    button[x] = new JButton();
    button[x].setFocusPainted(false);
    button[x].setBackground(Color.white);
    if (x > 6)
        button[x].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                day = button[selection].getActionCommand();
                d.dispose();
            }
        });
        if (x < 7) {
            button[x].setText(header[x]);
            button[x].setForeground(Color.red);
        }
        p1.add(button[x]);
}
JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
JButton previous = new JButton("<< Previous");
previous.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        month--;
        displayDate();
    }
});
p2.add(previous);
p2.add(l);
JButton next = new JButton("Next >>");
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        month++;
        displayDate();
    }
});
p2.add(next);
d.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
d.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
d.pack();
d.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
displayDate();
d.setVisible(true);

}

public void displayDate() {
for (int x = 7; x < button.length; x++)
    button[x].setText("");
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, 1);
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int daysInMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
for (int x = 6 + dayOfWeek, day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; x++, day++)
    button[x].setText("" + day);
l.setText(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
d.setTitle("Date Picker");

}

public String setPickedDate() {
if (day.equals(""))
    return day;
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, month, Integer.parseInt(day));
return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}

}

 class Picker {   

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Selected Date:");
    final JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
    JButton b = new JButton("popup");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(label);
    p.add(text);
    p.add(b);
    final JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            text.setText(new DatePicker(f).setPickedDate());
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: why do you want to re-invent the wheel? Especially, if the wheel is not exactly trivial. SwingX comes with JXDatePicker, you might want to look at how it's implemented

Comment: @kleopatra  I hear what your saying, but even so, I have to admire the OP's little date picker.  I never thought it could be so easy to get a basic date picker on-screen!  @bsm using a library date picker that has already been developed and comprehensively tested has definite advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the code required for you to make the calendar show under the button is below. But before you can use it, there are few changes to your code which you must (1), should (2) and could (3) make.

1. In the DatePicker constructor get rid off d.setVisible(true); since we are going to do some settings in the action listener before actually showing the dialog.
2. When you are creating the frame it is always useful to add this line f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); so your application will always close, otherwise you end up with tone of applications consuming your computer resources.
3. I would recommend for the Date Picker to extend JDialog instead of having the dialog as a variable. Because effectively that what the date picker looks like to be in your code.

```
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                DatePicker dp = new DatePicker(f);
                Point bP = b.getLocationOnScreen();
                dp.d.setLocation(bP.x, bP.y + b.getHeight()); 
                dp.d.setVisible(true);
                text.setText(dp.setPickedDate());
            }
        });
```

When it goes to the second part of your question considering size change Andrew Thompson answered it great, since you are already calling pack, any size modification are undesired.

Enjoy, Boro.

Comment: Good answer, since it addresses the OP's first question better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Speciall thanks to @Boro and @Andrew Thompson.

Comment: One thing in which still I didnt get success to solve is:How can we set the smallest(in which all the contents of calendar is visible) size of DatePicker(Calendar)? Should I have to set individually panel and all button's size?How can I get exactly which is the smallest size in which text of buttons is clearly visible? Should I go through trial and error method to find it?

Comment: I say you would have to set size of each cell in the date picker. To be minimal as possible set the size of each cell to fit two digits (assuming you are happy to cut down names of columns to two characters). Preferable to use FontMetrics here to get a width of a text in a font. But even better would be to use some layout manager to take control of component resizing instead of dealing with each component separately. My personal favourite is TableLayout. Having it I stopped using any GUI builders.

Comment: Yes I was also thinking to go through layout manager. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to see it just below the button. How can I do it? ..

[Component.setLocation(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29) or [Window.setLocationRelativeTo(Component)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29).

> ..How can I change the size of calendar to make it little bit small?

[Component.setSize(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29), or as trashgod suggested, a call to [Window.pack()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29).

The latter is better since `pack()` does the 'heavy lifting' of calculating how small the window (frame, dialog etc.) can be *without truncating the contents.*  It is not an easy task to determine the minimum size.

Comment: +1 but I'll argue against making it any smaller than `pack()`, which takes into account the L&F.

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect I think you are right.  `pack()` does the work for us, so why try to 2nd guess it?